# Making a easy and hard mode on quiz python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm writing this python code that will allow the user to chose a easy and hard mode with multiple choices. The questions for each mode are the same but the hard version just has more options to chose from in each question. This is my code so far:

```
questions = ["What is 1 + 1",
         "What is Batman's real name"]
answer_choices = ["1)1\n2)2\n3)3\n4)4\n5)5\n:",
              "1)Peter Parker\n2)Tony Stark\n3)Bruce Wayne\n4)Thomas Wayne\n5)Clark Kent\n:"]
correct_choices = ["2",
               "3",]
answers = ["1 + 1 is 2",
       "Bruce Wayne is Batman"]

def quiz():
    score = 0
    for question, choices, correct_choice, answer in zip(questions,answer_choices, correct_choices, answers):
        print(question)
        user_answer = str(input(choices))
        if user_answer in correct_choice:
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect", answer)
    print(score, "out of", len(questions), "that is", float(score /len(questions)) * 100, "%")

quiz()
```

How would I add the easy and hard more without making a new list and having to copy and paste everything? An explanation would also be nice. 
Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: You need to write code that generates the hard mode lists based on the easy mode lists and some additional information (the additional options). The best way to do this is mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: You need to look into dictionaries.

Comment: You should consider rephrasing `Bruce Wayne is Batman` to `Batman is Bruce Wayne` given how the question is posed :)

Comment: If it were me, I’d have a bunch of entries in a file for easy mode that are randomly chosen for the questions (along with the answers, maybe a dict?) then the same for hard mode to ensure the questions are mostly different each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a list of all the questions, and then splice it as necessary based on difficulty.

```
def get_choices(difficulty):
    choices = [
        "1)1\n2)2\n3)3\n4)4\n5)5\n:",
        "1)Peter Parker\n2)Tony Stark\n3)Bruce Wayne\n4)Thomas Wayne\n5)Clark Kent\n:"
    ]

    if difficulty == 'easy':
        choices = [c.split("\n")[:3]  for c in choices]
        return choices
    elif difficulty == 'medium':
        choices = [c.split("\n")[:4]  for c in choices]
        return choices
    else:
        return choices
```

If you could make each separate choice a list element and have a solution correspond to it, it would be simpler. You could then get the correct solution and shuffle the other answers and automatically assign numbers.

Comment: Work fine but how would I print each element on a new line? So that each element in choices is on a new line when printed. I think I can do the rest from there on

Comment: You could change this `user_answer = str(input(choices))` to simply print all the choices by iterating and then do `user_answer = input()` or use `'\n'.join(choices)` if you want to keep that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function blocks and call them basis on user input something like:

```
# define the function blocks
def hard():
    print ("Hard mode code goes here.\n")

def medium():
    print ("medium mode code goes here\n")

def easy():
    print ("easy mode code goes here\n")

def lazy():
    print ("i don't want to play\n")

# Now map the function to user input
choose_mode = {0 : hard,
           1 : medium,
           4 : lazy,
           9 : easy,

}
user_input=int(input("which mode do you want to choose : \n press 0 for hard \n press 1 for medium \n press 4 for lazy \n press 9 for easy "))
choose_mode[user_input]()
```

Then invocation of function block will be:

```
choose_mode[num]()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement something like that would be to start with an list that contains, for each question, the correct answer and the possible wrong answers.

Then, you would create code that would generate the actual question list from that base list, by picking, for each question, the correct amount of wrong questions, according to the difficulty level. That new list that was generated would then be used for asking the questions.